# Running old django app in new virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I have a django app i was running in python 2.7 and django 1.7.10.However am trying to transition it to django 1.8. I have created a new virtualenv,installed python2.7 and django 1.8 in it and moved the app there.However when i run the server it still reads django 1.7.10.What could be the problem ?

console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ONKi.png)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/upgrade-version/

Comment: i upgraded,but for some weird reason its still saying django version 1.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to move application for new virtual environment you just need to activate it probably you did not activate new one. Actually also you do not need a new virtual environment for upgrade. Just `pip install -U django==1.8`  it will upgrade your django and then make necessary edits.

Comment: thanks,i upgraded to django 1.8,then 1.7.10 was removed and it works !